# Steps to free up storage space in postgres database after deleting rows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm over the GB limit on a postgres db on heroku.

I found a (very large) deprecated table and ran `Plot.delete_all`. Now the 17k row table has 0 rows in it.

I can now see a difference in the row number but no difference in GB. Here's the Data Size before (37.73 GB)

```sh
heroku pg:info
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ONYX_URL, DATABASE_URL
Plan:                  Hobby-basic
Connections:           2/20
PG Version:            11.14
Created:               2019-03-09 12:13 UTC
Data Size:             37.73 GB/10.00 GB (Write access revoked; Database deletion imminent)
Tables:                6
Rows:                  2649450/10000000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow:           Unsupported
Rollback:              Unsupported
Continuous Protection: Off
Add-on:                postgresql-spherical-39745
```

and after (still 37.73 GB, despite rows decreasing 16610):

```sh
heroku pg:info
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ONYX_URL, DATABASE_URL
Plan:                  Hobby-basic
Connections:           3/20
PG Version:            11.14
Created:               2019-03-09 12:13 UTC
Data Size:             37.73 GB/10.00 GB (Write access revoked; Database deletion imminent)
Tables:                6
Rows:                  2649450/10000000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow:           Unsupported
Rollback:              Unsupported
Continuous Protection: Off
Add-on:                postgresql-spherical-39745
```

This `Plot.delete_all` will delete all the rows in the plots table, but is it sufficient to free up the disk space that the db was occupying with those records?

#### What I've tried

- `heorku restart` made no difference.
- I waited (60 minutes), but since [heroku's background workers update these statistics typically no less frequently than every 5-10 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22200538/5783745) I presume that the readings are accurate and the bloat is still there
- I ran the [postgress `CLUSTER`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5331819/5783745) command, but I think it only performs operations on tables that have previously been clustered, so it completed quickly and didn't seem to do anything nor affect disk space)
- I tried [`VACCUM`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5328108/5783745) but it finished quickly and didn't seem to affect disk space.
- I tried [`VACCUM FULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5328108/5783745) - this took about 1-2 hours and worked! See results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70872811/5783745).

#### Things I haven't tried yet, but may try

- I may edit the application code to remove the entire model, then `rake db:migrate` etc, and that should remove the unnecessary table entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Running [`VACUUM FULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327964/free-space-after-massive-postgres-delete/5328108#5328108) reduced the database disk size from 36GB to 16GB.

#### Here's how

1. Put your app into [maintenance mode](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maintenance-mode#usage):

```sh
heroku maintenance:on
```

2. Restart your app (this may not be necessary but I did it anyway)

```
heroku restart
```

3. Open the postgress console with

```
heroku pg:psql
```

4. Run this (note the `;` at the end of every SQL statement):

```
VACUUM FULL;
```

... wait ...

5. Once it's done, turn maintenance mode off

```
heroku maintenance:off
```

#### Important notes

- This process may take a few hours (it took about 1 hour for me)
- This process will *increase* the size of your database before decreasing it! That's because it creates copies of the data. The 36GB db went up to at least 44GB, possibly much higher (from a few related tests, I suspect approximately double the original size), before coming down to 16GB.
- Further reading [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/59896/153581) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-vacuum.html)

  - Note:

  > The `FULL` option is not recommended for routine use, but might be useful in special cases. An example is when you have deleted or updated most of the rows in a table and would like the table to physically shrink to occupy less disk space and allow faster table scans. `VACUUM FULL` will usually shrink the table more than a plain `VACUUM` would.

#### Extra info that may be useful

`heroku pg:vacuum-stats` could be useful:

```
heroku pg:vacuum-stats
 schema |        table         |   last_vacuum    | last_autovacuum  |    rowcount    | dead_rowcount  | autovacuum_threshold | expect_autovacuum 
--------+----------------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------------+-------------------
 public | listings             | 2022-01-27 01:31 | 2022-01-26 06:59 |      2,975,055 |              0 |        595,061       | 
 public | ar_internal_metadata | 2022-01-27 01:31 |                  |              1 |              0 |             50       | 
 public | metrics              | 2022-01-27 01:31 |                  |         17,016 |              0 |          3,453       | 
 public | plots                | 2022-01-27 01:31 | 2022-01-27 00:46 |              0 |              0 |             50       | 
 public | schema_migrations    | 2022-01-27 01:31 |                  |              7 |              0 |             51       | 
 public | packages             | 2022-01-27 01:31 |                  |         18,798 |              0 |          3,810       | 
(6 rows)
```

- [These](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage) incredibly useful postgres queries can be used to show each table and how much disk space it consumes! (highly recommend starting here, is it can show a breakdown of each table's size in your database).
- `VACUUM FULL;` will do all tables in the database. Use `VACUUM FULL plots;` to do just the plots table (replace 'plots' with your table name). It will probably be much faster.